# TraceView profiles TextView.<init> taking up the most time

Tags: android, performance, trace

My android app seems very slow whenever I create views, such as initial start up and every time I rotate it. I'm making an app with a lot of tables and textfields, upwards of around 50+ per Activity on a tablet.

I was thinking that maybe some horrible computation is happening that shouldn't be, so I did a traceview.

From the looks of it, one of the big methods that's taking up CPU Time is

```
android/widget/Textview.<init> --> Incl Cpu Time 31%
```

So basically, creating the view is why creating the view is slow.

That doesn't make sense to me because my app does not have that many layouts. I'm using TextViews and EditTexts, and my app has no images. It shouldn't be so ridiculously slow. Has anyone had slow onCreateView() + onViewCreated() resolved? Is there some magical way to make sure that my Views don't take forever to create/recreate on rotate?